# Gif image in windows form application causing memory leakage

Tags: c#, winforms, gif

I've used a gif image in PictureBox in windows form.
When I run my application, memory usage by the application keeps on rising.

Code is:

```
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("image.gif");
```

How may I get rid of this situation?
Thanks!

Comment: Put at least the stacktrace.

Comment: If the memory is full, GAC will clear it. Otherwise if(pictureBox2.Image != null) {pictureBox2.Image.Dispose()}

Comment: not exactly sure what the mechanics of picturebox.image are. but it just might be that the garbagecollector doesnt think its neccesary to free the memory yet so it keeps on rising

Comment: I've observed memory usage in Task Manager

Comment: everything else is just fine, but the problem is when I've a look at task manager my application memory usage is increasing.

Comment: and definitely at some time it will crash:(

Comment: i dont think you understand how a garbage collector works. try look it up

Comment: also the task manager is not that accurate whats wrong with the ide you are using? probably visual studio which is way better at indicating whats up.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation of the image class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see that the class implements **System.IDisposable**.

This means that the designer of this class would like to encourage you to actively make sure that Dispose() is called when you don't need the image anymore. The reason for this is because the designer of the class uses some scarce resources of which it would be good if they would be released as soon as the object isn't needed anymore.

In your case the scarce source is (among others) memory.

Of course the garbage collector will make sure that the object is disposed, but if you leave it to the garbage collector this won't be ASAP. Normally you are not sure when the garbage collector will clean up the memory.

So if you are loading images in a high tempo, Chances are high that your old images are not garbage collected before you load the next image.

To make sure the object is disposed as soon as possible you could use something like:

```
Image myImage = ...
DoSomeImageHandling (myImage)
// myImage not needed anymore:
myImage.Dispose();
// load a new myImage:
myImage = ... // or: myImage = null;
```

The problem with this is that if DoSomeImageHandling throws an exception Dispose is not called. the using statement will take care of it:

```
using (Image myImage = ...)
{
   DoSomeImageHandling (myImage);
}
```

Now if the using block is left, for whatever reason, whether is is left normally, or by exception or after a return or whatever, myImage.Dispose() is called.

By the way, in your case the scarce source is not only memory, the file is also locked as long as you don't dispose the image as the code below shows

```
string fileName = ...
Image myImage = new Image(fileName);
DoSomething(myImage);
// my image and the file not needed anymore: delete the file:

myImage = null; // forgot to call Dispose()
File.Delete(fileName);
// quite often IOException, because the file is still in use
```

The proper code would be:

```
string fileName = ...
using (Image myImage = new Image(fileName))
{
    DoSomething(myImage);
}
// Dispose has been called automatically, the file can be deleted
File.Delete(fileName);
```